# Taking User confirmation in drools 5.4

Tags: drools

I have a requirement in which

- if certain validation **fails**, I have to ask the user whether to **continue or not**.
- If user says **yes**, I have to `persist the data in DB` and
- if user says **no** then `data won't be persisted in DB`.
- The validations are performed in **validate.drl**.
- Once these validations are performed,I have to ask the user if he wants to continue or not. The process flow is as follows:

  Start -> input.drl -> validate.drl -> takeUserConfirmation.drl -> persistData.drl

In above flow, I have to add some logic in `takeUserConfirmation.drl` so that the user should confirm if he wants to continue or not. Depending on the answer given I’ll restrict the rule in `persistData.drl`.
So that it will only execute if the user confirms the persistence. How can I achieve this? Can the Human task i.e. **work item handler** is useful for this case? How to **pause the drools flow**, take the user confirmation and start the same flow again ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is why you want to do it all in Drools. Rule file doesn't seem to be right place for user interaction. I would rather return back to application code with collection of objects for which validation failed (you can flag them) and then if they will be confirmed execute presistData.drl for them.

So in final version you will have two separate flows:

- input -> validate -> persist (you can have additional flag on object validated which will be checked in persist)
- persist executed once more after confirmation

Also I wonder what is the purpose input.drl?

This should be rather comment than post but I don't have required 50 rep.

Comment: Input.drl is required to initialize some facts like inserting required Service classes to call persist method etc. Also I can't divide the flow into two parts as you suggested as it’s a common flow for my application. So if any validation fails in validate.drl,  takeUserConfirmation.drl will have some logic which will ask user whether he wants to continue or not and after user confirmation the flow will be resumes again.

Comment: My initial idea was to put some object into Drools globals and execute its blocking method returning result of confirmation. I never used work item handlers, but it seems that they can be really nice choice in your case (of course, if you can modify flow a little bit). In both situations the main problem seems to be invoking GUI operation, but how hard it in fact will be, depends mostly on technology that you are using.